# Azure logic apps - How to read message received from topic and insert into Salesforce

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a Azure Logic App. The workflow is triggered by "**When a message is received in a topic subscription (auto-complete)**".
The message is simple JSON format:

```
{
    "FirstName":"Test",
    "LastName":"User",
    "CreatedAt":"2022-03-26T19:27:07.6885324-04:00"
}
```

I want to insert the record into Salesforce. But I am unable to insert the record as I am not able to extract properties from message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parse_JSON` in this case. As the result we receive from the trigger is of base64, we need to use

```
decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])
```

Here is the screenshot of my logic app:

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add steps. I am able to add `decodeBase64()` but unable to proceed further.

Comment: Click on `Parse_JSON` content >> Expressions >> use `decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])` >> click OK. Please refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/fgWresr.png)

Comment: i got confused about `Compose` and then later realized it was  another step. Thank you